# How do I move a .NET aspx file from a project on one computer to the same project on another computer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a backup of our web application on another computer so I can work on it without disturbing the live version that's hosted on the server. 
I created two new aspx pages in the project and I wanted to know how to move just those two new pages into the live version of the website.

Any suggestions would help ! Thank you.

edit: I made changes to the entire project by adding a new web page. I want to move only that webpage to the server thats running the live version. It uses stored procedures. How do i transfer that to the server as well ?

Comment: Are you using any type of source control?

Comment: @ivcubr No I'm not using any SVC. No experience with it either.

Comment: If you're not using source control, you're making a giant mistake. Probably many giant mistakes. You should make that your top priority.

Comment: @mason I will look into getting a source control ASAP. But will it help for an already published website ?

Comment: If the published site is a website, and not a web application project, then yes. Otherwise, you'll need to find the original source code.

Comment: You can't. You have to redeploy the entire web application. Adding anything with a code-behind (you mention using stored procedures) requires recompiling and redeploying the DLL housing the compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Source Version Control ?

If the other computer is a dev machine, just use a SVC (tfs, git...).

If you want to update the production and both computers know each other (same network), just [publish the website with Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt.aspx).

Otherwise, publish in a local folder and copy the result of the publish in the bin folder of the production.

Comment: No, I'm not using any SVC. I will have to look into that for future use. The previous website was made by someone else. I'm new and trying to build up on it and I'm an amateur. 
The live published version (where I intend to transfer the new webpages) is published using IIS. Its local and not on the internet.

Comment: Yeah but with Visual Studio, you can publish a website to a server by network. If the computer cannot access to the server by network, you have to copy the content of the website manually on the server in the folder on the website.
To do that, you publish the website locally on the computer you use and copy the result on the publication on the server.
Do that only if you can't publish the website by network.

Comment: we had a backup of the entire website. Copy pasted on the computer i am working on. I opened this website in visual studio and started making changes. The only changes i made is adding a new web page. This new webpage only needs to be moved to the live version thats on the server. I'm not sure if I can publish only this one page. I would have to publish the whole project right ? Also, will that take care of stored procedures? or will i have to create them on the server again ?

Comment: The website and the stored procedures are two differents things.
You have to publish the whole project, you never know if some days you may miss one file.
To update the database:
If you use EntityFramework, use the command update-database with the right connection string (with migrations-based stored procedures).
Otherwise, get the sql scripts and run them of the Db.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The entire website project folder is hosted as a virtual directory using IIS. To be clear, I was working with a copy of the same project folder on another computer to which I added a two more web pages.

Step 1:
Copy the new web pages (.aspx) created and add it to the computer which is acting as the server.

Step 2:
Update the sitemap in the server computer by copy and pasting it.

Step 3: (optional)

IF you have created a new stored procedure ( I used SQL server management studio) and if you are on the same network as the server, you can run the same stored procedure with the target as the server. That way you don't have to copy the stored procedure code and create a new one manually on the server.